# When i run configserver project http://localhost:8888/limit-service/default does not return propertySources

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

[image: 1]

propertySources empty why?

application.yaml

```
server:
  port: 8888
 
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///C:/Users/hp/IdeaProjects/cloudconfig
          default-label: master
  application:
    name: spring-cloud-config-server
```

limit-service.yaml

```
limit-service:
  min: 10
  max: 1000
```

Comment: what do you get with this url :  http://localhost:8888/limit-service/master ?

Comment: @MohammadAdil same as in the picture. propertySources is empty

Comment: Also, make sure limit-service.yaml is committed in git repo

Comment: @MohammadAdil yeah, i sure. I solved my problem. I just added spring.profiles.active=native. Thx u for attention